# If possible, how can I query mysql database from a postgresql database?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, dblink

Is it possible to write just one query in postgresql database that can also fetch the data from mysql server? With dblink_connect feature of the postgresql database I was able to achieve this goal from another postgresql database but not mysql database. With mysql database it gives me connection refused error.

This is the query I used in a postgresql database and fetched data from another postgresql database:

```
create extension dblink;
select * from dblink('dbname=dbaname port=1234 host=123.456.678.321 user=username password=password', 'SELECT name FROM tbl_customer') AS newTable (mname varchar);
```

Comment: That's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use (and install) a foreign data wrapper.

[mysql_fdw](https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw) is one possible option.